# Spring Data JPA Many to Many with extra column User and Roles

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to use many-to-many relationships using spring boot JPA between `User` and `Role` entity.

I was able to achieve this using code below BUT in my requirement, I need **one extra column** in the pivot table(`users_to_role`).

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "users_to_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Role> roles;
```

Here is my new code

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   private String username;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="users", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<Role> roles;

   //getters and setters here
}
```

**Role.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   private String name;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="roles", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<User> users;

   //getters and setters here
}
```

**UserRole.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_to_role")
public class UserRole {

   @Id
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   private User user;

   @Id
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
   private Role role;

   private Date createdAt;

  //getters and setters here
}
```

Could someone help me to point out what I am doing wrong?

Here is error stack:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal use of mappedBy on both sides of the relationship: com.example.entities.Role.users
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because in your User Entity in `@OneToMany` you are specifying `mappedBy` as `users` while in your `UserRole`  Entity , `User` Entity is represented by the object `user` (not users). 
Similar is the case with Role Entity.

Just synchronize the value in mappedBy attribute with name of objects you are mentioning in `UserRole` .

Secondly in both `User` and `Role` Entities you should have `List<UserRole>`  (not the list of User or Role)because you will have foreign key in **users_to_role** table.

The following change will work

**User.java**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<UserRole> roles;
```

**Role.java**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<UserRole> users;
```

**UserRole.java**

```
public class UserRole implements Serializable {}
```

Comment: I tried to change mappedBy="user" in User.java and mappedBy="role" in Role.java but still error :(

Comment: Please check my edited answer to change list type in both the entities

Comment: thanks, not i am getting - Composite-id class must implement Serializable: com.example.entities.UserRole

Comment: Do i have to add @id?

Comment: You need to add Primary Composite key here with the help of Embeddedable and EmbeddedId and your user and role fields(as together they will form composite primary key) of UserRole will move to your Embeddable class.

Comment: Hi could you pls give me an example to insert?